# c# how to get through every item in a list when using list.Remove

Tags: c#

I have this code that has to remove all numbers from 1 to 700 containing digits bigger than 6

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Sevenland_Numbers
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> numbers = new List<string>();

            for (int i = 0; i <= 700; i++)
            {
                numbers.Add(i.ToString());

            }

            for (int i = 0; i <numbers.Count; i++)
            {
                if (numbers[i].Contains('7') || numbers[i].Contains('8') || numbers[i].Contains('9'))
                {
                    numbers.Remove(numbers[i]);
;
                }

            }
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(numbers[i]);
            }


        }
    }
}
```

but when I use Remove the list gets resized so I don't get through all the elements with the for cycle. Is there an easy way to fix this ?

Comment: Either go backwards in your `for` loop, or skip the increment when you remove.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simple way to do it:

```
var toRemove = "789";
numbers.RemoveAll(n => toRemove.Any(r => n.Contains(r)));
```

Comment: Note that in addition to be shorter, and easier to read, this will perform quite a bit faster as the items in the list call all be moved over at once, rather than constantly moving tons of items over in the list over and over again.

Answer (score 4):

Just decrement the counter after you call `Remove`.

```
for (int i = 0; i <numbers.Count; i++)
{
    if (numbers[i].Contains('7') || numbers[i].Contains('8') || numbers[i].Contains('9'))
    {
        numbers.Remove(numbers[i]);
        i--;
    }
}
```

That will cause your loop to repeat the operation using the same value, and will keep it from "skipping" over the next value in the list.

Of course, you could always use LINQ as well:

```
var numbers = new List<string>();
for (var i = 0; i <= 700; i++)
    numbers.Add(i.ToString());

numbers = numbers
             .Where(n => !(n.Contains('7') || n.Contains('8') || n.Contains('9')))
             .ToList();

for (var i = 0; i < numbers.Count; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(numbers[i]);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is.

Decrement the iterator index whenever you remove an element, like this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i <numbers.Count; i++)
 {
   if (numbers[i].Contains('7') || numbers[i].Contains('8') || numbers[i].Contains('9'))
   {
      numbers.Remove(numbers[i]);
      i--;
   }
 }
```

Alternatively, you may go through the list backwards (decrementing to 0):

```
 for (int i = numbers.Count-1; i >= 0; --)
 {
   if (numbers[i].Contains('7') || numbers[i].Contains('8') || numbers[i].Contains('9'))
   {
      numbers.Remove(numbers[i]);
   }
 }
```

That way, the math will handle itself out.

Answer (score 0):

normally i would use deleting loop:

```
for(int i = numbers.Count - 1; i > -1; --i){
    numbers.Remove(numbers[i])
}
```